# Task of composer dump-autoload

Tags: laravel, composer-php

What does this instruction

> composer dump-autoload

exactly do?

Especially before migrating in Laravel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you're asking about why do you need to run this command after creating a new migration file. This command will just recreate a list of autoloaded classes so Laravel could load this migration file. In other words, you're kind of registering the migration class.

http://developed.be/2014/08/29/composer-dump-autoload-laravel/